# How to pass a custom css class into a react modal?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap's Modal in my project. In the Modal component, there is a button:

```
<Modal ...>
 <Modal.Body>
  <button type="button" className="btn printBtn" onClick=  {this.validateUser}>Send</button>
 </Modal.Body>
</Modal>
```

in which, "printBtn" is a custom css class defined in a top level .css file. But it does not work. I have spent a few hours on this issue without luck. Can anyone please help?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does the button show, but without the class? Maybe the button doesn't show at all? Please explain what doesn't work.

Comment: And suggest you to provide relevant demo in Fiddle/Plunkr

Comment: Can you show the button css?

Comment: what is most likely happening is your `.printBtn {` class is being overridden by `.btn` because `.btn` is going to have other selectors before it.. aka `.modal .something .btn`. try adding !important after your css attributes in the custom class.... aka `color: blue !important;`

Comment: Thank you all. I tried "!important" but does not work. The button does show, but only '.btn' class is applied, not '.printBtn'. The problem only occurs in react-modal. if I move this button to the main page, .printBtn will be applied.

Comment: @Chris. Also, it seems all custom css classes are failed in react-modal. <Modal.Body> <div style={{color:"red"}}>good day</div></Modal.Body> works well. But if I define a custom class (.textColor {color:red;}) in a top level .css file, then <Modal.Body> <div className="textColor">good day</div></Modal.Body> won't work, aka, the red color is not applied.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `btn-` prefix when you want to add your custom className to the Button component.

**Read the caption [custom-styles](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#custom-styles).**

Comment: Thank you. But adding btn- does not work. The problem only occurs in react-modal, not in main page.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I was trying to style a button and a paragraph inside a modal, my class was being applied to the element but not the styles.

I think this is because the div modal is inserted outside of the root react div. **Try moving your styles to your index.html inside a style tag in the header section, it worked for me**. I don't love the solution but it should work.